# I am building portfolio by using Jquery plugin filterable.pack and also using lightbox2 to open images. what lightbox is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

I am using file below..

src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
src="js/filterable.pack.js">
src="js/prototype.js">
src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder">
src="js/lightbox.js">

please help.. or tell is there any conflict b/w jquery files or something else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery and Prototype in the same page, it's best to:

1. include jQuery *after* Prototype (so it has the `$` it can restore)
2. call [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) on jQuery, then use `jQuery` or whatever variable you set instead of `$`

Once you change the script order, it would look like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(".selector").myPlugin();
```

Comment: i have changed the order . but i don't understand rest of the part.I am not using it anywhere.

Comment: I am just calling jquery.noConflict().

Comment: @SecPro - that's fine...as long as you're using `jQuery` instead of `$` from then on to refer to jQuery, `$` will refer to Prototype after that.

Comment: thnx , i was able to solve it. using your hint or using my own techniques.